# How to parse a div class with space character

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, find

I am trying to parse a html file using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, I am facing a div with a class which contains a space character

```
<div class="camera_src camerastarted">
<div data-thumb="/images/articles/football/th/css_sg_th.jpg" data- src="/images/articles/football/css_sg.jpg">
```

I used the following code:

```
$link = $html->find('.camera_src camerastarted div');


print_r($link);

foreach ($link as $ligne) 
{ 
 echo '-- ' . $ligne->getAttribute('data-src') . '<br />';
}
```

But I got nothing as display, only: Array()

What's wrong? thanks for advance!

Comment: no idea if this would work but `$link = $html->find('.camera_src div, .camerastarted div');`

Comment: class names do not have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only one class like this

```
$link = $html->find('.camerastarted');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
    $link = $html->find('.camera_src.camerastarted');

Answer (score 0):

Notice there is an error in your HTML, a space in "data- src", not "data-src"
Of course you get nothing.